# max sort values not working for dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I have a dataframe called `stock1` consisting of 505 stocks, and their percentage change for a total of 52 weekly rows for each column.
I wanted to find the stocks with the maximum value for the final weekly row, so I did:

```
 import pandas as pd

 st1 = pd.DataFrame({"FIN_MAX": stock1.tail(1).max().sort_values(ascending=False)})
```

The above code originally worked, but now it throws an error.

```
 TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

The closest I can get to is if I drop the `sort_values(ascending=False)`, but then the values are not arranged in order from highest to lowest.

```
 st1 = pd.DataFrame({"FIN_MAX":stock1.tail(1).max()})
```

I've also tried the following code which also gives the same error as above.

```
 st1.sort_values(["FIN_MAX"], ascending=False)
```

I'm using Python 3.6.1 on Jupyter Notebook. 
Any help or alternatives would greatly appreciated.

It seems the error persisted due to a column created called `Unnamed: 0` when I concatenated all the stocks from individual csv files.
Once I did `del stock1["Unnamed: 0"]`, it seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

To get the stock with the largest value

```
stock1.iloc[-1].idxmax()
```

To get the stock with the largest value and the value

```
stock1.iloc[-1].nlargest(1)
```

To get the `n` stocks with the largest values and their values

```
n = 5
stock1.iloc[-1].nlargest(n)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick suggestions, piRSquared. So `stock1.iloc[-1]` is equivalent to `stock1.tail(1).max()`. Unfortunately, idxmax() gives a `ValueError` and `nlargest(1)` gives a TypeError. :/

Comment: I found the error. Looks like there was a Unnamed: 0 column produced that I had to delete. It seems to be working now, thansk piRS!

Comment: `stock1.iloc[-1]` is not the same as `stock1.tail(1)`.  The former returns a `pd.Series` object with the column values as the index.  The latter returns a `pd.DataFrame` with a single row being the last row.  When you call `max` or `idxmax` on a `pd.Series` it will return the index value (previously the columns from the `stock1`) associated with the maximum value.  Also, `nlargest` behaves distinctly differently in a `pd.Series` vs `pd.DataFrame` context and is the source of the `TypeError`